# Ignore string if empty in concatenation formula

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

I have a formula which concatenates strings in different columns. It works great when there is data in each of the columns but if one column is blank I get an error "invalid procedure call or argument" for the string formed by the empty column. Is there a clause i can add into my code to ignore the string if it is empty?

```
Sub Concatenation_for_the_nation()

'Range("H2").End(xlDown).Select
Cells(rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Select
For i = 1 To ActiveCell.Row
    Range("H" & i).Select
    StrStrONE = StrStrONE & "" & Selection
Next i
Cells(1, 1).Select

'Range("I2").End(xlDown).Select
Cells(rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Select
For j = 1 To ActiveCell.Row
    Range("I" & j).Select
    StrStrTWO = StrStrTWO & "" & Selection
Next j
Cells(1, 1).Select

'Range("J2").End(xlDown).Select
Cells(rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Select
For k = 1 To ActiveCell.Row
    Range("J" & k).Select
    StrStrTHREE = StrStrTHREE & "" & Selection
Next k
Cells(1, 1).Select

'Range("K2").End(xlDown).Select
Cells(rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Select
For l = 1 To ActiveCell.Row
    Range("K" & l).Select
    StrStrFOUR = StrStrFOUR & "" & Selection
Next l
Cells(1, 1).Select

StrStrONE = Trim(StrStrONE)
StrStrTWO = Trim(StrStrTWO)
StrStrTHREE = Trim(StrStrTHREE)
StrStrTHREE = Left(StrStrTHREE, Len(StrStrTHREE) - 3)
StrStrFOUR = Trim(StrStrFOUR)
StrStrFOUR = Left(StrStrFOUR, Len(StrStrFOUR) - 3)

Cells(14, 7) = "(ISAV(" & StrStrONE & " " & StrStrTWO & " " & StrStrTHREE & ")=1 OR (" & StrStrFOUR & ")=1)=1"


Cells(14, 7).Select



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the columns are not empty by using **ISBLANK()** function

Answer (score 0):

As user2471313 said used ISBLANK() function or I would add something like this for checking the string:

```
If StrStrONE<>"" and StrStrTWO<>"" and StrStrTHREE<>"" and StrStrFOUR<>"" then
    StrStrONE = Trim(StrStrONE)
''''your code until end
End if
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct idea, but I don't think it's necessary for **all** strings to be non-empty simultaneously, it's probably better to test each one in turn and `Trim` each in turn.

Comment: @asongtoruin just for sharing, sometimes Trim function also not really works from my experience. In this case, I need to find the specifics char then would replace them with "".